# jQuery return false necessary but breaking .each code

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I've been having issues with my page in iOS Mobile Safari- the page freezes on orientation change. My function is excecuted on `$(window).resize();` which is what Mobile Safari listens to for portrait/landscape orientation.

After wracking my brain and desperately trying things, I added `return false;` to the `.each();` section of my function and voila! Orientation Change no longer freezes! But...

Now the function isn't run for `.each();` of my defined elements.

How can I let the function run for all the elements while maintaining whatever behavior it is the `return false;` adds (which prevents Mobile Safari from freezing)?

Test site: http://brantley.dhut.ch/

THANK YOU!

JavaScript:

```
(function($){
$.respond = function(callback) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        dimensions();
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        dimensions();
        $('#load').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('.z:first').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#status').fadeIn('slow');
            $('footer').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        dimensions();
    });

    function dimensions() {
        var i = $('.z');
        i.each(function() {

            var browserWidth = $(window).width();
            var imgRatio = ($(this).width() / $(this).height());
            var availableHeight = ($(document).height() - $('header').height() - $('#status').height() - $('footer').height() - 80);
            var browserRatio = (browserWidth / availableHeight);

            if (imgRatio >= 1) {
                $(this).addClass('landscape');
            }

            if (browserRatio >=1.5) {
                $('#container').css('min-height', '360px');
            } else {
                $('#container').css('min-height', '555px');
            }

            if (browserRatio >= imgRatio) {
                /* landscape */
                //$('body').css('background', 'blue');
                $(this).height(availableHeight).width('auto').css('margin-top', '0');       
            } else {
                /* portrait */
                //$('body').css('background', 'green');
                $(this).width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto').css('margin-top', (availableHeight - $(this).height())/2);
            }

            $(this).css('margin-left', (browserWidth - $(this).width())/2);

        });

        return false;

    };

};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: First of all, why do you abuse with JavaScript, why are you omitting semicolons? Has it occurred to you that the "un-freezing" happened, because the loop broke out, thus, you should be looking in optimizing your loop?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? There arn't any syntax errors in this code... says Google's dev console

Comment: `var imgRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height() var availableHeight = ($(document).height() - $('header').height() - $('#status').height() - $('footer').height() - 80) var browserRatio = browserWidth / availableHeight` add semicolons.

Comment: Please read [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html);

Comment: @Shef- added the appropriate parens and semi colons, then ran through jslint. code is updated. So following your thought that the freezing is occurring because the loop is poorly written, what do you recommend?

Comment: There's many ways to optimize this loop, some of which are 1. Cache your selectors 2. move calculations out that you only need to do once e.g availableHeight and browserWidth, do you really need to calculate these over and over again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this optimized code:

```
(function($){
    $.respond = function(callback) {
        var $doc = $(document),
            $win = $(window),
            $z, $load, $footer, $header, $status, $container,
            resizing = false;

        $doc.ready(function() {
            $z          = $('.z');
            $load       = $('#load');
            $footer     = $('footer');
            $header     = $('header');
            $status     = $('#status');
            $container  = $('#container');

            dimensions();
        });

        $win.load(function() {
            dimensions();
            $load.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $z.filter(':first').fadeIn('slow');
                $status.fadeIn('slow');
                $footer.fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });

        $win.resize(function() {
            dimensions();
        });

        function dimensions() {
            if(resizing){
                return; // break; the function is still running
            } else{
                resizing = true;
            } 

            var browserWidth    = $win.width(),
                imgRatio        = $this.width() / $this.height(),
                availableHeight = ($doc.height() - $header.height() - $status.height() - $footer.height() - 80),
                browserRatio    = browserWidth / availableHeight;

            $z.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (imgRatio >= 1) {
                    $this.addClass('landscape');
                }

                if (browserRatio >=1.5) {
                    $container.css('min-height', '360px');
                } else {
                    $container.css('min-height', '555px');
                }

                if (browserRatio >= imgRatio) {
                    /* landscape */
                    //$('body').css('background', 'blue');
                    $this
                        .height(availableHeight)
                        .width('auto')
                        .css('margin-top', '0');
                } else {
                    /* portrait */
                    //$('body').css('background', 'green');
                    $this
                        .width(browserWidth - 40)
                        .height('auto')
                        .css('margin-top', (availableHeight - $this.height())/2);
                }

                $this.css('margin-left', (browserWidth - $this.width())/2);

            });

            resizing = false;
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return false;` is not in the `.each()` but rather in the event handler itself, meaning you're cancelling any pending events.

I assume that your function is causing another `resize` event to happen, thus causing endless loop.

Optimize the code by running the handler once plus use global flag to know you came from the function and it should work:

First part:

```
var _resizeTimer = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    window.clearTimeout(_resizeTimer);
    _resizeTimer = window.setTimeout(dimensions, 200);
});
```

Second part:

```
var _insideDimensions = false;
function dimensions() {
    if (_insideDimensions)
        return;
    var i = $('.z');
    _insideDimensions = true;
    i.each(function() {
        //.....
    });
    _insideDimensions = false;
}
```